# how to build a bash variable from docker build arguments

Tags: bash, docker

I have a docker file which I want to take in two build arguments

```
 ...
 FROM ubuntu:18.04

 ARG user
 ARG pass

 ENV MY_USERNAME = $USER
 ENV MY_PASSWORD = $PASS

 RUN echo ${MY_USERNAME}
```

here is how I execute

```
 λ docker build --no-cache --rm -f "Dockerfile" --build-arg user=someusername --build-arg pass=somepass .... etc etc
```

this strangely outputs

```
 Step 6/20 : RUN echo ${MY_USERNAME}
  ---> Running in 969c7da3e416
 = someusername
```

Shouldn't that equal sign not be there?? It's gotten in there somehow but I don't understand how to get rid of it.

Comment: omg once I posted the question, I see the problem.. it's the ENV line not needing the equals signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables) it seems that you don't need the equal sign when assigning an ARG variable to an ENV one.

So your Dockerfile should be:

```
 FROM ubuntu:18.04

  ARG user
  ARG pass

  ENV MY_USERNAME ${user}
  ENV MY_PASSWORD ${pass}

  RUN echo ${MY_USERNAME}
```